# \AtBeginPage + itemize

Tags: macros

I would like to start every page of a document with some text that may include LaTeX constructions such as `\begin{itemize}`.

The following MWE does not works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{bophook}

\AtBeginPage{\begin{itemize}\item Test\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea about this issue?

PS: I may also want to add in this "at the beginning of the page" text more complex structure such as `\begin{mdframed}`.

PPS: The text I want to print at the beginning of every page is aimed to be a reminder of my goals of the text I'm writing: it won't appear in the final version of the document.

Comment: that `bophook` package has not been updated in 20years!!!! Note that if your LaTeX installation is 100% up to date, the kernel now has hooks build into it that should make this easy.

Comment: Try `\AtBeginShipout{` from `atbegshi` package

Comment: don't use this package, it relies on internals for hyperref for which there is no garanty that they will stay this way. Use the new latex hooks, e.g. shipout/background or the eso-pic package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Package `atbegshi` is independent of `hyperref`. Package `atbegshi` does not even depend on LaTeX, it can be used in plain TeX. `hyperref` is just one of the packages that is using `atbegshi`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I didn't mean atbegshi but this bophook package, it uses commands like `\ifHy@pageanchor`, `\@hyperfixhead` and `\HyPL@EveryPage`. Sorry, I see now that my remark could be easily related to the comment before.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe, you can give an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use the package `atbegshi` and the command `\AtBeginShipout{...}`.

Answer (score 7):

The contents of `\AtBeginPage` is typeset in a horizontal box, so it cannot make paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bophook}

\AtBeginPage{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{itemize}\item Test\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```