# Text at the beginning of every page

Tags: macros

I was wondering how can I automatically insert some predefined text at the beginning of every page ?
I am not talking about some kind of header, just regular text automatically added on the first line of every page.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your issue better ...

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580399/270674

Comment: Bascally, you can not do this. Page breaking happens asynchronously after one or more paragraphs have been set, you can not reflow a paragraph based on it being at the top of a page. (Also you would have to define what "first line" meant if there were top floats inserted.)

Comment: Should this mysterious "regular text" be inserted on a line by itself, should it become part of the running text of the current paragraph (continued from the previous page), or maybe something else? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico it should stand as the first characters seen in the page so become part of the running text of the current paragraph

Comment: @HasanBasriÇetin Yes, but this is not respecting the margins defined by geometry and this is displayed on top of the text already there

Comment: your request is not unreasonable but basically unsupportable without extensive rewriting of latex. It is like having an image at the top corner and having text flow round the image if it falls at the top of the page. It is a common design but basically unsupported in TeX

Comment: @gruvw if you insert a line of text in the page hooks or page head it can be of any length and position you choose so you can make it match the margins and you can make it not overprint the main text but come as if the line above.

Comment: You might also check the flowfram package.